# Change Remote Url Dynamically jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to change remote url dynamically, when i fill the input, work normally, but when i click "load.php" button, its still load the "check.php". help me.

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="validate">
      <input id="testremote" name="testremote"  type="text" data-rule-remote="check.php" required data-msg-required="Please Fill" >
        <br/><br/>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<button onclick="changeurl('load.php');">Change URL(load.php)</button>
<button onclick="changeurl('test.php');">Change URL(test.php)</button>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#validate").validate();
});

function changeurl(a){
var x = $("#testremote");
x.attr("data-rule-remote",a);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Apparently, you can **not** dynamically change the `remote` URL:  http://jsfiddle.net/gdusgax2/ ~ As per this demo if you change the URL immediately when loading the page, it sticks, but you cannot change the URL after you've tried submitting the form.

Comment: The real question is **why** you'd need to do this in the first place?  Simply send the data to the same URL and handle the various conditions on the server instead.

Comment: I want to use this for my edit form,  when i update data that must access load.php, but when i insert data for the first time that access check.php (check the data if exist in database)

Comment: Like I said, you can handle these conditions within your server side logic rather than trying to change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your console in dev tools, you will see error `validate() is not a function` or something like this. This error causes that script execution ends here because of this error and function `changeurl()` is not even created.

But why `validate() is not a function` ?
This means that something is wrong with link through which is library included. To solve it just replace `http` with `https`.

`<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

If I'm not wrong I think that if one of resources is loaded via `https` other resources with `http` will be ignored. But I'm not sure about it.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: It's like you're answering a question from another page.  The OP said nothing about getting any errors, in fact, he is describing the opposite.  He stated that `remote` rule is working, but not with the URL as dynamically updated via his function.  If the `remote` rule is working, then there are no errors with `.validate()` being recognized.

Comment: I don't know, I copied his code and run it and it threw an error.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know what is the error. Everything works well for me.

Comment: If it's working well for you, then you don't have errors and I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: That's an issue specific to your browser.  The validation plugin is working fine for me with mixed protocols:  http://jsfiddle.net/82q4gpq9/